# How to use touchscreen to draw?

Tags: touchscreen, touchegg

I have tried different softwares for drawing using my touchscreen (e.g. Gimp or Krita).
However, when I touch and drag (to draw a line) what happens is that only the mouse pointer moves from one place to the other, but as I was not "clicking" to draw.

I also cannot use some gestures such as zooming a picture.

I have installed Touchegg, but I'm not sure how to use it and if it can help me solve this problem.

Comment: While this may not be applicable to your specific touch screen, I used the Gimp with a Thinkpad X60 tablet, which utilizes a stylus, and this worked fine for drawing.

Comment: @Dev Thank you, but that's not really a solution to the problem... The touchscreen should work as well as in Windows, and it doesn't.

Comment: @cinico It is a temporary solution until you can find a real solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First install `touchegg`:

```
sudo apt-get install touchegg
```

Install the dependencies for the GUI tool (for TouchEgg) using this command

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libqt4-dev libx11-6 libx11-dev
```

Download the GUI [`touchegg-gce` from GitHub](https://github.com/Raffarti/Touchegg-gce). Then:

> 1. Change to the directory holding the .zip file.
> 2. Issue the command `unzip Touchegg-gce-master.zip` to extract the file.
> 3. Change into the Touchegg-gce-master folder.
> 4. Issue the command `qmake`
> 5. Issue the command `make`
> 6. Copy the `touchegg-gce` file to `/usr/bin`

Source: [How to Configure a Touchscreen on Linux](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-configure-touchscreen-linux)

Under "Touchegg" it shows you how to configure the program, maybe this'll allow you to draw on your touchscreen. I am sorry I am unable to help further as I don't know much about this program.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to install touchegg, as I mentioned. But it is the problem on configuring it correctly that I couldn't solve because I think I did everything correctly, but still can't draw I as explained...

Comment: Assuming you completed the 6th step, open Touchegg and click "Add", I'm guessing you'll be drawing with one finger so in the Dialog I'd make Fingers: 1, Gesture: hold, Direction: up (but you'll have to make this same motion configuration 4 times for all the directions, and more for diagonals if possible) Action: drag(?) I'm sorry, I would love to test this out but can't; I wanted to try to help seeing as no one else offered a solution. Its worth trying. You could also try changing the Action to "click" and whatnot and see if it works as should.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to hold down the mouse button while drawing. This gives you the advantage of not clicking accidentally when bumping the screen for example.

Comment: He's using fingers on a touchscreen, not a mouse. Why use a mouse on a touchscreen?

Comment: @ipselute I know, I'm just saying hold your mouse button down *while you're using fingers on the touchscreen*.

Comment: That's a good one!!! Ha, ha, ha! Just use a cheap mouse instead of an expensive touchscreen! Point taken. Akiva used a stylus that worked, i guess it's a problem of touch sensitivity threshold.

Comment: @ipselute you're so sassy